# Check certificate for expiry in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-networking

is there a way to check if a certificate is valid or reporting on certificates that are due to expire for websites in Azure, these are not web apps?

Hope that makes sense

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are the webservers running on VMs?

Comment: @Louis  hi Louis, yes they are, we are looking for a cloud native tool to inspect certificates

Answer (score 0):

You can use CertBit to automate renewals.

It runs as a service, and us free, as are the certs:

Instructions are given for a given setup in their sites: https://certbot.eff.org